# Form the input tensor correctly for LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

I have a time serieses of two features (atributes) for each user. Am I shaping the input tensor for LSTM correctly?

Suppose I have two users and they have two features (atributes):

```
s1 = np.array([
    (u1_f1_t1, u1_f2_t1),
    (u1_f1_t2, u1_f2_t2), 
    (u1_f1_t3, u1_f2_t3)])  # series for user1

s2 = np.array([
    (u2_f1_t1, u2_f2_t1), 
    (u2_f1_t2, u2_f2_t2)])  # series for user2
```

Here f - feature, t - time, u - user.

The input tensor is so

```
X = sequence.pad_sequences([s1, s2])
```

Is the correct input tensor shape

```
X.shape = (number_of_users, length_of_timeseries, number_of_features)
```

?

The model has the form

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(None, 2)))       
model.add(LSTM(...input_shape=(None, 2) ...))
```

where 2 is the number of features.

P.S. add example code

```
user1_timeseries = np.array([[11, 1], [22, 3],  [33, 4]])  # two features and three time steps 
user2_timeseries = np.array([[10, 3], [20, 1],  [30, 2], [40, 2]])  # two features and four time steps
user1_class = np.array([1])
user2_class = np.array([0])
timeseries = [user1_timeseries, user2_timeseries]
classes = [user1_class, user2_class]
X = sequence.pad_sequences(timeseries)
y = sequence.pad_sequences(classes)[:, :, np.newaxis]
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=10, input_shape=(None, 2), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(units=10, return_sequences=False))    
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**is this attempt at solving the time series classification problem correct?**

Comment: to prepare data for lstm from dataframe/2d array, you can use [this](https://ai4water.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils/#ai4water.utils.utils.prepare_data) function

Comment: @AtherCheema thanks for the answer and the library. But, in the specified method, the slicing of the input tensor is performed by a sliding window (utils.py, line from 1240).

I need to solve a binary classification problem - to predict the long-term absence of user activity. In this case, the entire range of user features (attributes) is marked up, and not part of it.